# How do I white list a phrase before validating it for special characters using Java Regex package

Tags: java, regex, validation

Hey I need to bypass the validation for substring **whiteList** in the string **str** but the rest of the string needs to be validated for the special characters '<', '>', '$', '#', '@'.

Assuming that substring is not repeated anywhere else in the main string.

**This is the main string**
`String str = "blah blah blah X has paid $8,894 to the shop owner blah blah blah"`

**This is the sub string**
`"String whiteList = "x has paid $8,894 to the shop owner"`;

**current validation for the main string**
`boolean specialChar = Pattern.compile("<|>|\\$|#|@", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(str).find();`

The substring **whiteList** contains $ which should not be validated and should return false.

I am looking for a solution using regular expression if its possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go around it:

```
String stringToCheck;
int pos = str.indexOf(whiteList);
if (pos >= 0) {
    stringToCheck =
        str.substring(0, pos) + str.substring(pos + whiteList.length());
} else {
    stringToCheck = str;
}

boolean specialChar =
    Pattern.compile("[<>$#@]").matcher(stringToCheck).find();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about java. Just curious because of the regex involvement.

What about this using this regex:

```
[^\s<>$#@]+\shas paid [\d,]+ to the shop owner
```

- It will only catch the required part from the main string
- The variable part in this match is the word before `has` for which we can use `^` to avoid such chars presence
- Input like `blah blah blah ><$ has paid 8,894 to the shop owner blah blah blah` will be no match for the substring.

P.S. sorry if this is not relevant.